# Why is there a low rate of kidney disease related deaths in the Baltic countries?

Tags: pathology

A noticeable feature of the map of kidney disease related deaths is that the Baltic countries, Norway, Finland, Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, etc have lower rates:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: The poor separation between the color scale makes it really hard to tell what the rates are, except for the high countries. I'm not convinced that the Baltic countries have lower rates. Are there actual numeric data anywhere?

Comment: would be really useful to have a link to the source.

Comment: To me, the best correlate of cancer rate here looks like population. I wonder if this is a similar effect to Gelman's US kidney cancer example.

Comment: Affluent countries have higher rates of diabetes which is the major cause of renal disease.

Comment: [Baltic countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_states) include only Estonia, Latvia, and Lithuania. And if you meant [baltic region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_region), then what countries are included is a little bit up to everyone's defintion but you would definitely include Russia (which rate of Kidney disease is quite high). So what countries did you mean exactly?

Comment: Looking at this map I can't see any obvious difference with the baltic states (or states of the baltic region of whatever you meant). Mongolia, central Africa or central America does not seem to have a lower rate of kidney diseases.